# Auto-scroll to selected widget in ListView.Builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a horizontal ListView.builder consisting of widgets with month names in them and the idea is to auto-scroll to the widget with the current month when this screen is navigated to. I have been able to go as far as showing the widget with the current month pre-selected but cannot seem to auto-scroll to that. I get the below error every time I try doing so:

```
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
```

Here is my code:

```
final selectedItem = GlobalKey();


  List<Map<String, dynamic>> months = [
    {
      'month': 'Jan',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Feb',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Mar',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Apr',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'May',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Jun',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Jul',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Aug',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Sep',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Oct',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Nov',
      'onclick': false,
    },
    {
      'month': 'Dec',
      'onclick': false,
    },
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    current_mon = now.month.toString();

    print(
        'CURRENT MONTH: ${monthFormat.format(DateTime.parse(now.toString()))}');

    for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
      if (months[i]['month'] ==
          monthFormat.format(DateTime.parse(now.toString()))) {
        setState(() {
          months[i]['onclick'] = true;
          scrollToItem();
        });
      }
    }

    Map data = {
      // "month": "",
      "month": '',
      "all": 1,
      "year": myYears.toString(),
    };

    claimz_list.postClaimzHistoryList(context, data);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> scrollToItem() async {
    final selectedContext = selectedItem.currentContext;

    await Scrollable.ensureVisible(context,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          current_mon = months[index]['month'];

                          // months[index]['onclick'] = false;
                          // if (months[index]['onclick'] == true) {
                          //   setState(() {
                          //     months[index]['onclick'] = false;
                          //   });
                          // }

                          for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
                            if (months[i]['onclick'] == true) {
                              setState(() {
                                months[i]['onclick'] = false;
                              });
                            }
                          }

                          setState(() {
                            // isClicked = true;

                            months[index]['onclick'] = true;
                          });

                          Map data = {
                            "month": current_mon.toString(),
                            "all": 1,
                            "year": myYears.toString(),
                          };
                          if (kDebugMode) {
                            print(data);
                          }
                          claimz_list.postClaimzHistoryList(context, data);
                          //Provider.of<ClaimzHistoryViewModel>(context,listen: false).postClaimzHistoryList(context, data);
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: SizeVariables.getWidth(context) * 0.04),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            key: selectedItem,
                            backgroundColor:
                                const Color.fromARGB(174, 51, 51, 51),
                            radius: 40,
                            child: Center(
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                child: Text(
                                  months[index]['month'],
                                  style: months[index]['onclick'] == false
                                      ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall
                                      : Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .bodySmall!
                                          .copyWith(color: Colors.amber),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      itemCount: months.length,
                    );
                  }
                }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

When I try doing the below, I get this error:

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();


ListView.builder(
                      // key: selectedItem,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      controller: scrollController.animateTo(offset, duration: duration, curve: curve),   //I get the error at this line
                      // itemScrollController: listScrollController,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          current_mon = months[index]['month'];

                          // months[index]['onclick'] = false;
                          // if (months[index]['onclick'] == true) {
                          //   setState(() {
                          //     months[index]['onclick'] = false;
                          //   });
                          // }

                          for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
                            if (months[i]['onclick'] == true) {
                              setState(() {
                                months[i]['onclick'] = false;
                              });
                            }
                          }

                          setState(() {
                            // isClicked = true;

                            months[index]['onclick'] = true;
                          });

                          Map data = {
                            "month": current_mon.toString(),
                            "all": 1,
                            "year": myYears.toString(),
                          };
                          if (kDebugMode) {
                            print(data);
                          }
                          claimz_list.postClaimzHistoryList(context, data);
                          //Provider.of<ClaimzHistoryViewModel>(context,listen: false).postClaimzHistoryList(context, data);
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: SizeVariables.getWidth(context) * 0.04),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            // key: selectedItem,
                            backgroundColor:
                                const Color.fromARGB(174, 51, 51, 51),
                            radius: 40,
                            child: Center(
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                child: Text(
                                  months[index]['month'],
                                  style: months[index]['onclick'] == false
                                      ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall
                                      : Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .bodySmall!
                                          .copyWith(color: Colors.amber),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      itemCount: months.length,
                    ),
```

The error:

```
The argument type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollController?'
```

Answer (score 0):

add ScrollController to the ListView.
then you can animate or jump to your item by knowing its index in the list then multiplying it by the width of the item like this:

```
scrollController.animateTo(
    itemIndex * (itemWidth + itemPadding),//add padding of the item if exists for accurate position
    duration: const Duration(microseconds: 800),
    curve: Curves.decelerate,
);
```

or use [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to work. I have updated the question with what I have tried and also the error that I'm getting. Can you please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: check this: [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list). i hope this helps with your problem.